How to call an async function in TMS WEB Core?
I've got a simple function in Delphi that is marked as an [async] function.
Currently, the function doesn't do anything. It literally just returns a Boolean value of True:
[async]
function MyAsyncFunction(): Boolean;

implementation

function MyAsyncFunction(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

But then every time I try to use the function like:
if MyAsyncFunction then
begin
  // Do Stuff
end;

then I get the following error:

[Error] Boolean expected, but Context found

What is Context and what is the correct way to call an async function in TMS WEB Core using Delphi?

Do you understand what asynch means?

https://www.tmssoftware.com/site/blog.asp?post=744

@DalikaPrasnikar gave a great link in the comments regarding async in TMS WEB Core.
Turns out that I simply had to wrap my call to MyAsyncFunction in an Await function like this:
if Await(MyAsyncFunction) then
begin
  // Do Stuff
end;

And then it works
But you need to mark the method you're calling from as [async] as well otherwise you'll get an await only available in async procedure error.
